# Python: proportional editing vertex move

Tags: python, scripting, transforms, edit-mode, vertices

I'm new to scripting in blender. Is there a way to proportional-edit a vertex through python?

I want translate a vertex along z, with all vertexes between that and local_Z=0 moving accordingly like they would in proportional editing

This is a graphical representation:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

look at the doc: http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_76_release/bpy.ops.transform.html?highlight=proportional#bpy.ops.transform.transform

By the way you can look in the 'action log' of the info editor (window header). enlarge it, sroll down, select entry it with your select mouse button and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to copy the command for your action

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working. I just get the dreaded: `convertViewVec: called in an invalid context` whenever I try using a function like this in my script: `bpy.ops.transform.translate(value = vtrans, constraint_axis=(False, False, False), ...`

Comment: @toddoeh Proportional editing needs to be run in the context of the 3d view. The text editor or python console is not a 3d view.  Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75960/python-what-is-the-right-context-for-bpy-ops-transform-delete-orientation-ope