# Python, what is the right context for bpy.ops.transform.delete_orientation() operator

Tags: python

I'm trying to delete a Custom Transform Orientation using script, for a Custom Transform Orientation that I created using script, creating it is a breeze, no problems at all, deleting it on the other hand is a mystery, trying to execute the operation:

```
bpy.ops.transform.delete_orientation()
```

I'm getting a context is incorrect error, I tried to get the right context using the following hack, but it's not working for this specific operator, it worked for create_orientation() but not for delete_orientation():

```
import bpy
types = {'VIEW_3D', 'TIMELINE', 'GRAPH_EDITOR', 'DOPESHEET_EDITOR','NLA_EDITOR', 'IMAGE_EDITOR', 'SEQUENCE_EDITOR', 'CLIP_EDITOR', 'TEXT_EDITOR', 'NODE_EDITOR', 'LOGIC_EDITOR', 'PROPERTIES', 'OUTLINER', 'USER_PREFERENCES', 'INFO', 'FILE_BROWSER', 'CONSOLE'}

area = bpy.context.area.type

for type in types:

    bpy.context.area.type = type

    if bpy.ops.transform.delete_orientation.poll():
        print(type)

bpy.context.area.type = area
```

Looking at the System Console after running the script above, is printing nothing, as if this operator is not available in any context in Blender! Even when I delete the Custom Transform Orientation from the Properties Shelf > Transform Orientations in 3D view, by clicking the X, nothing appears as executed in the Info Window!! Is it even possible to delete a Custom Transform Orientation using Python? I wonder why it's so easy to create one, and so hard to delete, if any one knows how to escape this incorrect context error, or how to delete a Custom Transform Orientation using a different method, would be appreciated.
Check the screen shots:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override the context of the operator:

```
import bpy

name = 'Edge.001' #The orientation to remove

views = [area.spaces.active for area in bpy.context.screen.areas if area.type == 'VIEW_3D']
if views: #Assign the orientation in the view so that it is active and can be removed
    views[0].transform_orientation = name

areas = [area for area in bpy.context.window.screen.areas if area.type == 'VIEW_3D']

if areas: #Give the good override context
    override = {'area' : areas[0]}
    bpy.ops.transform.delete_orientation( override )
```

Edit: following the comment, some 'novice' explanations

Operator's context can be override. An override is a dictionary with some keywords. Among them you have the 'area' (because we have bpy.context.area). And if you look in the N panel where a custom orientation can be deleted, you see you are in the view3D area.

So... we just need to give a view 3D area to the override context.

Edit again:

What you did in your code is changing your current context (the view itself)... but that does not change the execution context itself (where delete_orientation is called), that is changing only the view.

More information [here](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.ops.html)

#### Update:

In order not to get a ( *Pycontext '' not found* ) error in the system console, it's better to write the code this way:

```
...
if areas: #Give the good override context
    override = bpy.context.copy()
    override['area'] = areas[0]
    bpy.ops.transform.delete_orientation( override )
```

Reference: [here](https://developer.blender.org/T37079)

Comment: Works like a charm, I still don't get it though, but it works, I'll leave understanding research for another day, many thanks!